# Appcelerator third party framework arm64 error

Tags: ios, frameworks, titanium, appcelerator, arm64

I am trying to create an module for an third party framework in iOS. The framework is AdjustSdk.framework.
My Modules name is vgueAdjust.

I created the module like in

[the docs of appcelerator.com](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Project-section-43288810_iOSModuleProject-AddaThird-PartyFramework)

shown and integrated it in my testapplication.

But the testapplication builds with Errors:

> [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED ** [ERROR] :  The following build commands
>   failed: [ERROR] :     Ld
>   build/Intermediates/testapplication.build/Debug-iphoneos/testapplication.build/Objects-normal/arm64/testapplication
>   normal arm64 [ERROR] :    Ld
>   build/Intermediates/testapplication.build/Debug-iphoneos/testapplication.build/Objects-normal/armv7/testapplication
>   normal armv7 [ERROR] :  (2 failures)

I use:

Titanium SDK: 5.3.0

Module:

-Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

-Build Active Architectures Only: NO

-Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s

The AdjustSdk.framework is listed my vgueAdjust.xcodeproj in "Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries"

In my "Framework Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" is "$(inherited)"

The module is also build vor i386 and x86_64

> vgue:1.0.0 vgue$ xcrun lipo -info libvgue.adjust.a 
>   Architectures in the fat file: libvgue.adjust.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64
>   arm64

My tiapp.xml contains:

```
<modules>
    <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
    <module platform="iphone">vgue.adjust</module>
</modules>
```

and my module-manifest:
architectures: armv7 arm64 i386 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have to add following line to your module.xcconfig:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework AdjustSdk
```

In any case you need to find full description of error but not only "Ld failed"

Also you need to put AdjustSdk into platforms/iphone (or iphone/Resources after 5.2.0) folder.

> iphone/Resources
>
> Directory for platform-specific assets. This is analogous to the app/platform directory in a standard Titanium application project, and contains platform-specific assets that are not processed by Titanium but copied over to the module's package. For example, place any third-party frameworks or bundles you want to use with the module in this folder. Note: This directory will only be recognized in Titanium Mobile 5.2.0.GA and later.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Project

Comment: `OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework AdjustSdk`
is in module.xcconfig

i tried it with AdjustSdk.framework in platform and Resources folder.

nothing helps